# regex, extract string NOT between two brackets

Tags: regex

OK regex question , how to extract a character NOT between two characters, in this case brackets.

I have a string such as:
word1 | {word2 | word3 } | word 4

I only want to get the first and last 'pipe', not the second which is between brackets. I have tried a myriad of attempts with negative carats and negative groupings and can't seem to get it to work.

Basically I am using this regex in a JavaScript split function to split this into an array containing: "word1", "{word2 | word3}", "word4".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What 'bar'? That's not in your example.

Comment: What language or tool are you using ? Can you show us some of what you have tried ?

Comment: @CarlNorum He means `word1` which is before the **vertical bar** `|` :)

Comment: sorry about that. I changed the word 'bar' to 'pipe' in the question above. thx.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try using this pattern

```
/\|(?![^{]*})/g
```

with this text

```
word1 | {word2 | word3 } | word 4 | word 4 | {word2 | word3 }
```

This should match all of the Pipe symbols that are not inside {}.

*edit - removed link to dead site (Thanks Dennis)

Comment: very helpful, specially for html strings that need some replacement in their nodes, but not in their attributes ;)

Comment: refiddle.com doesn't link to the place you wanted it anymore

Answer (score 23):

Depends on the language/implementation you're using, but...

```
\|(?![^{]*})
```

This matches a pipe that is *not* followed by a `}` except in the case that a `{` comes first.

---

The `(?! ... )` is known as a *negative lookahead assertion*. This is easier to understand if we start with a *positive* lookahead assertion:

```
\|(?=[^{]*})
```

The above only matches a pipe that *is* followed by a `}` without encountering a `{` first. When you negate that by replacing the `=` with a `!`, the match is now only successful *if there's no way* for the positive case to be true (also known as the *complement*).

Comment: Why not just use a look ahead here?

Comment: @hwnd - Hm, perhaps it's possible, but I'm not seeing a way. Would you post what you're thinking? I'm curious!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So few of these are followed by explanations.