# Restrict string split between particular values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string like this

```
var str = "error,#FFFFFF,won,25,[{\"color\":\"#7ac1de\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"60\"}]"
```

I will be splitting the string based on comma (',') in the string. But i need to split the string with out affecting comma inside `[{\"color\":\"#7ac1de\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"60\"}]`. 
So my expected output will be `['error', '#FFFFFF', 'won', '25', '[{"color":"#7ac1de","from":"10","to":"60"}]']` .
I tried with many ways but not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```js
var str = "error,#FFFFFF,won,25,[{\"color\":\"#7ac1de\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"60\"}]";

var split = str.split(/,(?![^{]*})/);

console.log(split);
```

[Regex source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415051/1267304)

Answer (score 0):

This will provide your expected output: (checked)

var str = "error,#FFFFFF,won,25,[{\"color\":\"#7ac1de\",\"from\":\"10\",\"to\":\"60\"}]";

var res = str.split(",");