# Split string with square bracket

Tags: php, python, regex

I'm trying to use preg_split to split this text

```
Yes, it was great. [I have no ideas how great it was.]
```

into this array:

```
['Yes', 'it', 'was', great', '[I have no ideas how great it was.]'
```

But I don't know how...

Comment: What if the square brackets contain square brackets as well?

Comment: Do you want to do this in Python or in PHP?

Comment: What is `preg_split` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon Based on what I remember of PHP naming, it's the PHP equivalent of Python's `re.split`. (The `preg_*` functions are the regex functions that come from PCRE, as opposed to `ereg_*` for POSIX extended regex and `reg_*` for some builtin functionality that nobody should ever use.)

Comment: We could assume that the square brackets don't contain square brackets. I just need the regular expression used to split the strings, so i think any language would be fine

Comment: @abarnert Correct and in PHP, POSIX has been depreciated in later versions. So pretty much exactly like `re.split()`.

Comment: why is this tagged python?

Comment: @Xorifelse It looks like `ereg_` is deprecated as you said, and `reg_` is long gone, so… good news for people stuck using PHP, I guess. :)

Comment: @DuyHoang; you think bad, each language has these own methods with eventually different behaviours. As an aside, using a split method is the bad way. It's easier to build a pattern for a global match ( `preg_match_all` with PHP, or `re.findall` with Python)

Comment: `preg_split()` seems like the wrong tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,.]+(?![^[]*])/", "Yes, it was great. [I have no ideas how great it was.]");
print_r($keywords);
```

Comment: There would be a chance for a huge benefit if you'd explain what you are doing here.

Comment: I tried to write a simple explanation for 15 minutes, but failed. Found almost same problem already solved and explained. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414553/1921796