# Regex - split if not inside the two characters

Tags: javascript

example string:

```
hello ! < and ! world>, and ! letter and [another ! letter] here.
```

Let's say, I want to split the sentence by `!` character if it is not between `<` and `>`and also not between `{` and `}`.

I have been using :

```
str.split(/\!+(?=(?:(?:[^<]*"){2})*[^>]*$)/g);
```

to split if not between `<` and `>` , but how to add the another clause `{` and `}` too?  Putting `|` doesnt solve, because it might then match blended `<` and `}`..

Comment: Assuming your reger works, just duplicate with the second delimiter and put an or `|` in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/!(?![^<]*>)(?![^{]*\})/g`

`!(?![^<]*>)` matches a `!` if it is not followed followed by a `>`, unless it is preceeded by a `<`. [Gotten from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414553/745808)

Then simply chained with another negative lookahead for the second set of delimiters.

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ghr1vcwd/)