# Use read.csv but keep the quote marks

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a csv file that has quote marks in it

```
 id, value, other
 1, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 2
 2, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 3
```

read.csv removes the quote marks so I end up with

```
 id, value, other
 1, (a=b, b=c, c=d), 2
 2, (a=b, b=c, c=d), 3
```

Anyone got a smart on how I can keep the quote marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change the separators.

We can change the separator to something else and using `fread` works.

```
data.table::fread(gsub(',(?![^\\(]*\\))', ';', text, perl = TRUE), quote = '')

#   id                         value other
#1:  1 "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")"     2
#2:  2 "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")"     3
```

regex for `gsub` has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414553) to replace those commas that do not occur between `()`.

**data**

```
text = 'id, value, other
 1, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 2
 2, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps:

```
library(readr)

# simulating your data
id <- c(1,2)
value <- c('"("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")"', '"("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")"')
other <- c(2,3)

# creating a dataframe 
df <- data.frame(id, value, other)

# creating a csv file
write.csv(df,"mydata.csv", row.names = FALSE)

# Import csv dataset
mydata <- read_csv("mydata.csv")

# View data
View(mydata)
```